# How can I 'accumulate' a raw stream in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, stream

At the moment I concatenate everything into a string as follows

```
var body = '';
res.on('data', function(chunk){
    body += chunk;
});
```

How can I preserve and accumulate the raw stream so I can pass raw bytes to functions that are expecting bytes and not String?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, check that these functions *actually* need the bytes all in one go.  They really should accept `'data'` events so that you can just pass on the buffers in the order you receive them.

Anyway, here's a bruteforce way to concatenate all data chunk buffers without decoding them:

```
var bodyparts = [];
var bodylength = 0;
res.on('data', function(chunk){
    bodyparts.push(chunk);
    bodylength += chunk.length;
});
res.on('end', function(){
    var body = new Buffer(bodylength);
    var bodyPos=0;
    for (var i=0; i < bodyparts.length; i++) {
        bodyparts[i].copy(body, bodyPos, 0, bodyparts[i].length);
        bodyPos += bodyparts[i].length;
    }
    doStuffWith(body); // yay
});
```

Comment: what is `.copy()` method?

Answer (score 36):

Better use [Buffer.concat](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength) - much simpler. Available in Node v0.8+.

```
var chunks = [];
res.on('data', function(chunk) { chunks.push(chunk); });
res.on('end', function() {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    // Do work with body.
});
```

Comment: A much better method.  Saved me loads of time, thank you

Comment: this should be the accepted answer - no libraries, no deprecated apis. Thanks man!

Comment: I am having this error `[ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "list[0]" argument must be one of type Buffer or Uint8Array. Received type string`

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you can also use a node.js library like bl or concat-stream:

```
'use strict'
let http = require('http')
let bl = require('bl')
http.get(url, function (response) {
  response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
    if (err)
      return console.error(err)
    console.log(data)
  }))
})
```